# Bash command completion with custom function, regex on current completed word not working?

Tags: bash, bash-completion

I'm writing a custom completion function for a bash script (this script is for activating deactivating nginx configuration files). I'm trying to have a different behavior if the completed word starts with `--`, is empty, or starts with something else. Typically, if I write `command --<TAB>`, I should have `--help --someoptions` suggested, whereas if I type `command <TAB>` then I should have the content of a specific directory, matching a specific regex, shown as completion suggestions.

Here is the code of my completion function:

```
#!/bin/bash

source "./common"

_comp_nginx_conf(){
    local IFS=$' '
    local cur long_help conf_files new_help
    cur=
    long_help=( "help" "test" "testmode" "deactivate" "activate" )
    
    # for correct completion, check if test mode is in the options
    for arg in "${COMP_WORDS[@]}"; do
    if [[ "$arg" == "--test" ||  "$arg" == "-t" ]]; then
        TEST_MODE=true
    fi
    done
    
    [[ $TEST_MODE ]] && cd "$TEST_PATH" &> /dev/null || cd "$PROD_PATH" &> /dev/null
    
    conf_files=$(ls -b *(.conf|.conf.incative) 2> /dev/null)
    new_help=()
    COMPREPLY=()
    cur="$2"
    
    if [[ $cur =~ "--".* ]]; then
    
    COMPREPLY=( $(compgen -W "${long_help[*]}" -P "--" -- $cur) )
    
    else
    
    COMPREPLY=( $(compgen -W "${conf_files[*]}" -- $cur) )
    fi
    
    return 0
} &&
    complete -F _comp_nginx_conf nginx-conf
```

The issue here is, when I type `command --<TAB>` it should offer `--help --testmode --deactivate --activate` and when I type `command <TAB>` it should offer `test.conf test2.conf.inactive` and all the conf files in `$TEST_PATH`, but instead it still offers `--someoptions`.
I don't understand why I get this result, so this is where I need help, how to achieve the behavior I want and why don't I get it with the code I wrote?

Comment: Aside: `${conf_files[*]}` doesn't really make sense: `conf_files` is already a single string, not an array. (And separately, `array=( $(...anything...) )` is bad practice; see [BashPitfalls #50](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#hosts.3D.28_.24.28aws_.2BICY.29_.29))

Comment: I'm just tinkering around the edges, though, because digging into the question would involve getting into completion logic, and I stay clear of it as a matter of course (I dislike things that happen behind my back more than I like convenience). If you can extract a narrower description of what's going on that focuses on the bash language rather than on completion, I'd be glad to take a closer look; think about using `set -x` to get a trace of execution to figure out _exactly_ which operation first does something contrary to your expectations, to ask a narrower question about that one step.

Comment: It seems it must be something about `if [[ $cur =~ "--".* ]]; then` (that I don't see either!) ... wrap that block in `set -x` and `set +x` and confirm that variables are being expanded as you expect. Good first Q! Keep posting!

Comment: I doubt this is the problem, but regex matches don't have to match the entire string, just somewhere *in* the string, so [[ $cur =~ "--".* ]] will match "--" anywhere in the string, not just at the beginning. Instead, use `[[ $cur =~ ^"--" ]]` or a glob pattern like `[[ $cur = "--"* ]]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I find your function too complicated. `*(...)` is an extended glob. For the `-P --` you have to `${cur%--}` remove the dashes, otherwise they won't match. And I do not get the "TEST_MODE" - why would you want confuse users by changing directory in completion function! I use `set -x` for testing. Also function definition always succeeds, why `&&` of it.

```
_comp_nginx_conf() {
    local cur
    cur=$2
    if [[ $cur == -* ]]; then
        COMPREPLY=($(compgen -W "--help --test --testmode --deactivate --activate" -- $cur))
    else
        COMPREPLY=($(
            compgen -G '*.conf' -- $cur
            compgen -G '*.conf.incative' -- $cur
        ))
    fi
}
complete -F _comp_nginx_conf nginx-conf
```

Overall, why care at all, compgen will just return nothing:

```
COMPREPLY=($(
     compgen -W "--help --test --testmode --deactivate --activate" -- $cur
     compgen -G '*.conf' -- $cur
     compgen -G '*.conf.incative' -- $cur
))
```

If you want to complete files from some directory, change the directory in the subshell. I would be very confused if my PWD would change when executing completion.

```
local dir IFS=" "
case " ${COMP_WORDS[*]} " in
*" --test "*|*" -t "*) dir=$TEST_PATH; ;;
*) dir=$PROD_PATH; ;;
esac
COMPREPLY=($(
     cd "$dir" 2>/dev/null
     compgen -G '*.conf' -- $cur
     compgen -G '*.conf.incative' -- $cur
))
```

Check your scripts with shellcheck. Prefer `if` over `&& ||`.

Comment: You've found the solution, but you've made a mistake while giving me the answer, the solution was using ```${cur#--}``` to remove the extra --